# ¿Cómo asignar del año a registros de fecha?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, google-bigquery

tengo una tabla donde tengo fechas del 09-2021 hasta 01-2018   donde debo asignarle una etiqueta de año más reciente, esta etiqueta se debe asignar  un año para atrás cuando sea más del año debe cambiar la etiqueta ahora a la año que tiene reciente, la imagen es lo que quiero que salga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si actualiza la tabla fecha debe respetar el mismo criterio del etiquetado

```html
SELECT 
c1.fecha,
concat("MAT ",EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (c2.FECHA))) AS MAT
from `table` as c1
INNER JOIN `table` as c2 ON  c1.FECHA BETWEEN c2.FECHA AND DATE_ADD(c1.FECHA, INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
group by c1.fecha, MAT
order by c1.fecha desc
```

el código que tengo no me respeta la etiqueta de año asignado cuando llega a diciembre se cambia la etiqueta de año

Comment: y cual seria el problema?

Comment: no me respeta los 12 meses cambia el año cuando esta llega diciembre

Comment: No entiendo.. de que 12 meses hablas? que tiene la fecha que estas tocando?

Comment: Debo etiquetar 12 meses con el año más reciente, cómo ves la etiqueta mat 2021 corta en la fecha 01-10-2020 porque ya fueron 12 meses, la fecha 01-09-2020 debe empezar el mismo ciclo

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas, para poder entender mejor, y de preferencia los datos en texto

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta